# If block error handling in bash

Tags: bash

I have if statements with multiple lines of code in bash, sometimes while running the script any of lines of code thrown error message so could you please let me know how  to handle errors. I just wanna catch the error and display some error message to identify, and also I do not want to stop the running scripts, since it has 7800 lines of code I wanna continue with the next steps. each test steps are inside if loop. I want to know how to handle errors inside the if loop which having series of lines of code.

Thank you so much for help.

Comment: Firstly, Bash does not have any concept of "throwing" an error, so you must be misunderstanding what's happening. In order to solve your problem, you'll have to figure out what these commands are *really* doing. Secondly, *7800 lines*?? That's a really bad sign. This script is probably insane, and probably needs significant reworking.

Comment: Depends on the error.  There are many errors where it would be dangerous to continue.  I suggest that having a script of 7800 lines of code is poor design and it should be decomposed at least into functions that you can isolate and test.  More likely it should be split into separate scripts, or you are using the wrong language.

Answer (score 1):

You have basically the option to check the error code after each command. Especially for commands which do fail. This is quite similiar to checking return codes of C library functions. It glutters the code with error handling, so it is good to do it in reuseable functions.

You can do this by checking the `$?` error code variable, but more typically you use the fact that shell evaluates a 0 exit code as a boolean true.

Therefore For single commands, it can be done with the `||` (or) list operator which evaluates the second term (shell function) only if first returned false (aka non zero exit code aka error):

```
function die { echo "$1" 1>&2 ; exit 1; }

mkdir ./bla || die "Cannot create directory ./bla errno=$?"
```

bash (shell) normally proceeds after an error, which can produce quite unexepcted situations. For example in this case, if temp directory does not exist the script will detroy the content of current directory:

```
cd /home/user/temp
rm -rf *
```

So it is a good thing to turn this behavior off by setting "set -e".

```
set -e
cd /home/user/temp
rm -rf *
```

Or be specific about dependencies (by using `&&` and list operator instead of newline or `;`):

```
# execute rm only if cd was sucessful
cd /home/user/temp && rm -rf *
```

So it is typically a good idea ([caveat](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)) to turn on the "exit on error" mode. 
In this case commands which you want to be allowed to fail, need to be guarded like:

```
set -e
cd /home/user/temp
rm -rf * || true # ignore failures
```

And finally more complex error handling for blocks of code is done with a finish trap handler. It is executed when the program exits, and you can use it to print errors. This can be compared with try/catch in other programming languages, but it is more low level background interpretation on certain defined conditions:

```
function errorhandler
  { echo "Unexpected error while cleaning dir: $1 - $2"; exit 1 }

# try-start - capture errors
trap "errorhandler $LINENO $BASH_COMMAND" ERR

cd /home/user/temp
rm * || true # dont trigger error handler here

# try-end - stop capturing errors
trap - ERR
```

Traps (`trap "cleanup_function" EXIT`) are also [typically used](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) (beside signal handling) for unwinding/ceaning changes and temporary resources at the (unexpected) end of a program block.

Comment: +1. However, note that `set -e` is very error-prone, and it's debatable whether it should be recommended. (See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105.)

Comment: thanks @ruakh I added the link as a warning (personally I think its a saner default especially for quick scripts which have no error handling).